# Actions-on-Google - Error on saving Assistant and simulator failure

Tags: actions-on-google, api-ai

I was trying to test my app using the simulator which shows that **test status** is **active**, but it doesn't recognize the app and returns a response "*Sorry, this action is not available in simulation*". The app already has actions set without any errors, as I was able to verify the text version using the "Web Demo" from integration section. So, I tried adding the remaining app information and keep encountering the issue displayed on the image below.

All required fields have been filled, though they're not being saved.

Any ideas where this might be going wrong? I have scoured through the docs, but haven't found a solution yet.

**App Information**

[image]

---

**Simulator**

[image]

Comment: Please reach out to our support team: https://developers.google.com/actions/support/

Comment: Have you tried invoking the app with the name of the app you specified in the Actions Console?

Comment: @matthewayne I have, but got the same response. I'm going to start from scratch and see if I can see where it went wrong.

Comment: Hey @LeonNicholls , My simulator is still not recognizing the app. I have reached out to support team, but they haven't been very helpful at all and have stopped responding completely. Is there someone at Google support I could reach directly?